# vi mode to emacs mode while on R

Tags: r, bash, emacs, vi

Sometimes while on the R console I accidentally type an unknown keyboard short cut that changes the editing mode from emacs to vi.

Does anyone know what is usually this combination of keys to change from one to the other?

I am on a Fedora 16 machine

I checked the info on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640141/is-there-a-way-to-switch-bash-or-zsh-from-emacs-mode-to-vi-mode-with-a-keystroke) but using meta+v or meta+e doesn't change anything.

UPDATE: The keystrokes shown the answer below work **ONLY WITHIN R**!

Comment: Seems odd that bash (or whatever) doesn't behave in the default GNU readline, but this may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640141/is-there-a-way-to-switch-bash-or-zsh-from-emacs-mode-to-vi-mode-with-a-keystroke

Comment: Thanks for the link but is the same I posted in the question before. Even though I added the lines `"\M-v": vi-editing-mode
"\M-e": emacs-editing-mode` to my `/etc/inputrc` file I couldn't see any difference. I must be doing something wrong. I will keep my results posted.

Comment: oops, sorry.  (note that this part of the question has evolved so that it's no longer an R question: perhaps add a comment to the other question and see if someone responds?)

Comment: Obligatory "solution" :  http://xkcd.com/378/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R uses the GNU readline library for keyboard editing modes. I think the answer is therefore `meta-ctrl-j`, based on these links: http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC22 ,
http://www.algorithm-forge.com/techblog/2009/09/shortcuts-in-r-under-unix-from-the-readline-library/ ...

(I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 under VMWare on MacOS 10.6, so I actually have to hit the`Alt-fn-j` key combination to switch modes.  I've never done it by accident!)

**edit**: as pointed out by the OP, `Ctrl-e` goes back from emacs to vi mode.  http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?readline+3 does say

> ```
>    "C-E"  emacs-editing-mode
> ```

but this was pretty hard to dig up!

Comment: `Alt+Ctrl-j` works perfectly to go from emacs to vi but I am stuck now  in vi mode and `Alt+Ctrl-j` is unidirectional

Comment: While on vi mode `Ctrl-e` takes you back to emacs mode.