# How to make zsh keybind between emacs mode and vi mode?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I want to bind a key to toggle emacs mode and vi mode,which I use oh-my-zsh plugins([vi-mode](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/vi-mode)).

I tried [Is there a way to switch Bash or zsh from Emacs mode to vi mode with a keystroke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640141/is-there-a-way-to-switch-bash-or-zsh-from-emacs-mode-to-vi-mode-with-a-keystroke)

I also try to bindkey like 
`bindkey '^[e' 'set -o emacs'` 
`bindkey '^[v' 'set -o vi'`

But it's not work for me.

Does any way to toggle vi/emacs or keybind to set keymap? 
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bindkey` is used for binding keys to ZLE widgets not any random command. So what you have guessed at is not going to work. You could write a custom ZLE widget to switch keymaps:

```
select-emacs() { set -o emacs }
zle -N select-emacs
bindkey '^[e' select-emacs
```

In practical terms, I wouldn't recommend this. If you want a hybrid approach, it is better to select emacs mode but bind a key to `vi-cmd-mode`. In fact Ctrl-X,Ctrl-V is bound to this by default. You might even bind the escape key to `vi-cmd-mode` - where emacs key sequences involve an initial escape press, that can mostly be replaced by Alt. If you're used to typing it with the actual escape key, you may be able to replace it by a custom widget in vi command mode.

Comment: I try to bind key like this:

function select-emacs() { set -o emacs }
zle -N select-emacs
bindkey '^[e' select-emacs

function select-vi() { set -o vi }
zle -N select-vi
bindkey '^[v' select-vi

But it only work for  one way if
set -o emcas to keybind Alt-v(switch to vi mode)
or 
set -o vi to keybind Alt-e(switch to emacs mode)

Comment: but it can't switch from Alt-e to Alt-v or Alt-v to Alt-e
And then, setting by this function will not be written to os?
`set -o | grep 'emacs\|^vi'` will not change

Because this is [local keymaps](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Local-Keymaps) ?

Comment: To be able to switch back and forth, you need to bind `select-emacs` in the `vi` keymap and `select-vi` in the `emacs` keymap. Use the `-M` option to `bindkey`. local keymaps are totally unrelated to this whole question.

Comment: Thanks it works !
But I curious about why  zsh setting not change ?
`set -o | grep 'emacs\|^vi` the keymap setting will not change.

Comment: The zsh keymap setting is controlled and viewed with `bindkey`, it isn't a real option. Support for doing `set -o emacs` etc was tacked on later for ksh and bash compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I finally "found out" how to toggle vi and emacs mode with a singel key, e.g. [alt]+[i] in zsh

```
# in the .zshrc
# toggle vi and emacs mode
vi-mode() { set -o vi; }
emacs-mode() { set -o emacs; }
zle -N vi-mode
zle -N emacs-mode
bindkey '\ei' vi-mode              # switch to vi "insert" mode
bindkey -M viins 'jk' vi-cmd-mode  # (optionally) switch to vi "cmd" mode
bindkey -M viins '\ei' emacs-mode  # switch to emacs mode
```

now you can toggle from emacs-mode to vi-mode and from vi-mode (both insert or normal mode) to emacs-mode

Comment: Thanks for your advise.
In this way. I need to change the keybinding setting for like this:
bindkey -M emacs '\ei' vi-mode
bindkey -M viins '\ei' emacs-mode
This is work with ZSH 5.8